# PHP drop down list from database - how to restrict selections to 8 by date

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am doing web booking system for spa treatment with two selection. What I'm trying to do but it didn't work: Once we select the date, the selection on the drop down list will be limited based on the date where we can only select 8 value per day.

**First selection[input]** : contains `date` [yyyy-mm-dd]  [date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL2qG.png) (Click link for **HTML**)

```
    <div class='pt-2'>
      <div class='dates'>                
        <input type='text' autocomplete='off' class='form-control' placeholder='Treatment date' id="reservation_date" required style='background: none; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black;'/>
      </div>
```

**Second selection[dropdown]** : contains `treatment` list from database [treatment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqDMg.png) (Click link for **HTML**)

```
    <div class='pt-3'>
        <select id="treatment_name" style='width: 100%; background: none; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-style: italic; color: #4E4E4E;  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Arial"; opacity: 0.8'>
        <option>Treatment Name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

**Php code**:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM treatments ");

if($query){
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            echo '<option value="'.$row['t_name'].'">'.$row['t_name'].'  </option>';
            }
    }
    else 
        echo "error";
```

Can any one know how to limit `treatment` based on `date`? With condition, the users are allowed to booking treatment for 8 slot only per day(date). What I means is to set the condition where the `treatment` can only be select 8 times in one specific `date`.

My `problem` here at is when user select the `treatment` more that 8, it will automatically  `displaying messages` "Please choose another date for booking treatment since its already full on your selected date. Thank you." before click submit.

```
    //submit form
    $("#submit").click(function(){
      var customer_id= $("#customer_id").val();
      var reservation_date= $("#reservation_date").val(); 
      var reservation_time= $("#reservation_time").val();
      var treatment_name= $("#treatment_name").val();
      var reservation_status_id= $("#reservation_status_id").val();
      var blood_thinning= $("#blood_thinning").val();
      var herbs= $("#herbs").val();
      var others= $("#others").val();
      var infection= $("#infection").val();
      var menses= $("#menses").val();
      var pregnant= $("#pregnant").val();


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
      url: "booking_process.php",
      data: {customer_id:customer_id,reservation_date:reservation_date,reservation_time:reservation_time,treatment_name:treatment_name,reservation_status_id:reservation_status_id,blood_thinning:blood_thinning,herbs:herbs,others:others,infection:infection,menses:menses,pregnant:pregnant},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $('#add_booking')[0].reset();
      }//data
    });//ajax
  });//submit
```

Can any senior member guide me how to achieve it ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second drop down, might it be nicer to 'grey out' the treatments which are unavailable? - and perhaps even colour code those that have only one or two slots left

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Where **exactly** are you stuck? That is already a lot of code. Maybe you are not looking for a way to limit the list, but to filter it by a given start date?

Comment: The code are working just fine like when click submit it will enter into the database. Yeah...i need to set the condition where the treatment can only be select 8 times in one specific date. For example, 27/2/2019 = 4 slot treatment, 28/2/2019 = 7 slot treatment, 29/2/2019 = 8 slot treatment. But each date cannot have more than 8 slot for treatment.

Answer (score 0):

First dropdown is not a dropdown it's an text input. My answer is based on that you have a list of dates.
Make another table like date_limit or something like that and specify the limit on specific dates in your database (i dont know in what way your limits work so i'm not sure about the best way to do that).
When you generate the select list of dates you attach that value to the select value.

```
<option value="dd/mm/Y" data-limit="4">dd/mm/Y</options>
```

Then for the second dropdown just keep checking how many values are selected and what is the limit set on the first one.

If you're gonna use the text input for dates, you can basically do the same thing, but you need to send a query on each user date input and fetch the limit on the entered date.